# How to disable CTRL+Shift+A screenshot on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

It's been a very bad day since I am always losing in my CS: GO matches due to the switching from game to windows all because of this weird problem I am facing, each time I crouch and move left in the game which requires me to hold CTRL, Shift and A together Windows takes a screenshot and takes me to a cropping tool.

I am not sure if this is window's native or some other app (I checked Task manager there were nothing that could tell me if it was a third-party app)

Following is a screenshot of the cropping tool's interface, any idea which third-party app it could be? I have browsed my PC can't find such.

[image]

Comment: Which version of Windows? What is the name of the cropping tool?

Comment: Windows 10. I am not sure what's the cropping tool, there's nothing else just blue border, a small toolbar with square and circle shapes.

Comment: While there are [several different ways](https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/5-ways-to-open-snipping-tool-in-windows-10.html) to open the Snipping Tool on a Windows 10 machine, there isn't a native [keyboard shortcut](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12445/windows-keyboard-shortcuts) that should be causing this.  As a result, it sounds like it is something with your customized software configuration.

Comment: @Run5k There actually is a shortcut, Win+Shift+S. Which is very close to Ctrl-Shift-A...could that be it?

Comment: @wysiwyg, it is always wise to consider all the possibilities when you're troubleshooting.  But at the same time, *"very close"* is a subjective assessment.  While the keys may be in close proximity to one another, I would hope that the OP would have the wherewithal to realize if they were pressing **two**-out-of-three keys that are actually different from what they intended to do.

Comment: I actually tried CTRL+Shift+A, as I was confused while I was in game, so I tried all, `WASD` keys and it turned out to be `A`.

Comment: Is that Lightshot, perhaps? Similar toolbar, maybe an older version? https://app.prntscr.com/en/index.html

Comment: @Run5k I agree. Was just putting that out there that however unlikely, perhaps OP was just button mashing. That does not sound to be the case though.

Comment: I had lightshot installed before but not any longer, even I suspected it to be it, but it's not in my Chrome's extension's list neither any other photo or screenshot related app / extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Garena client uses this hotkey for screenshots - I suspect its due to that

[image: Screenshot of the Garena client settings screen]

Comment: A very late response from my side. Also because the system I had this problem was not with me any longer, but I am marking this as the accepted answer as I did have Garena installed and so it was probably it. 

For others it might be other tools / software.

Answer (score 3):

**SHORT ANSWER**: Lark app is the culprit (at least for me)!!

I had the same problem (messing up with me playing CS:GO as well!!!) and I stumbled upon this question here as well. Seems like we have the same software installed (see my screenshot below)

[image]

It wasn't like this before so I tried closing some apps that I have recently installed. And voila! When I closed Lark, pressing CTRL+SHIFT+A no longer triggers the screenshot.

*Answering this question just in case you haven't solved this yet even if 2 years had already passed or someone might have the same problem as well just like me*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For me it was definitely not Lark as I never had it installed, for me it was probably Garena as I remember installing it on my system where this problem occured. 

Thanks for your input, it may help people with Lark!

Answer (score 2):

Try Nirsoft's [ShortcutsMan](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shman.html), which displays the shortcuts in the Start menu and from the desktop. However, the shortcut you show, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, is more likely one in the game, and could be configured there.

Comment: please check my post, I updated it with an image. I tried the program but what I am supposed to look at? It's definitely not the game's as it works outside the game as well.

Comment: @DeepakKamat Click the Hot Key column to sort it by that, and see if there's a Ctrl-Shift-A entry. https://i.imgur.com/Nvwp5ZT.png Keep in mind though that this program will not necessarily show every shortcut-activated program on your system.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing this same issue with ctrl+shift+A and it was the same screenshot interface. I came looking for help and I was looking for help in your question too. Somehow I figured it out myself. It is the screenshot shortcut of the DINGTALK desktop application.

go to DingTalk settings and at the bottom you can find it
[press X button and remove it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwxLG.png)

Answer (score 0):

That is UC browser, If you have UC browser installed on your PC then you will have that problem. Check if that only appears when UC browser is open. Disable UC Browser and try again, good luck.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to go to the shortcut preferences of the last applications you installed. you will probably find the ctrl+alt+a assigned to some function. In my case it was ZALO that assigned the shortcut to a windows sreenshot option.